# @(t) mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

As the title suggest, what exactly does @(t) mean in Matlab given the context below? computeNumericalGradient is a function and cofiCostFunc is also a function that takes in a bunch of parameters. The question is what exactly is the @(t) doing to the cofiCostFunc function?

```
computeNumericalGradient( ...
                @(t) cofiCostFunc(t, Y, R, num_users, num_movies, ...
                                num_features, lambda), [X(:); Theta(:)]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@(t)` is what is known as an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).  `@(t)` will thus return a **handle** to a function that takes in one variable `t`.  Basically, it's a function that takes in one parameter, `t`.  The rest of the parameters are defined previously in your workspace.

What you are doing here is that the first parameter to `computeNumericalGradient` takes in a **function** where `t` is a variable that is defined by you.  As such, your `computeNumericalGradient` takes in **two** parameters:

1. An anonymous function that is defined like before.
2. A single 1D vector with two column vectors concatenated with each other - The first column is `X`, and the second column is `Theta`.

As a sidenote, if you were to do this:

```
func = @(t) cofiCostFunc(t, Y, R, num_users, num_movies, num_features, lambda);
```

You would thus call this function by doing `func(t)`, where `t` is whatever variable you want that is relevant to the function at hand.  The code would thus simplify to:

```
computeNumericalGradient(func, [X(:); Theta(:)]);
```

I'm not familiar with what you're doing here, so that context will have to be figured out by you.

Answer (score 1):

It is a handle to an anonymous function. I'm guessing computeNumericalGradient is expecting a function with one parameter (t). This essentially redefines cofiCostFunc as a function of only t by providing the remaining values.

You can read more here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-4

Comment: Upvoted to bring you to the next tier of privileges.  Sorry to beat you to the punch :( but still good answer!

Comment: Haha thanks :) I actually upvoted your post after seeing the simulpost. Great explanation.