# What does `@(x) myfun(x, F_index)` means in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function, handle

What does `@(x) myfun(x, F_index)` means in MATLAB? What does it call and return?

For example in this application:

```
fmincon(@(x) myfun(x, F_index), ...)
```

Please provide more examples and explain them if possible.

Comment: This is an [anonymous function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: That construct (`@(x) ...`) is called an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).  It creates a variable that is essentially a function.  The usage here indicates that the anonymous function is being used to [parameterize](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) `myfun`.  Please see the documentation for more details.

Comment: Why don't you comment [on the answer you were given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367531/error-using-fmincon-matlab) for clarification?

Comment: possible duplicate of [@(t) mean in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726320/t-mean-in-matlab) – also [what is @ operator in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100595/what-is-operator-in-matlab) and [Call functions with @() in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966517/call-functions-with-in-matlab/24973974#24973974)

Comment: This is another question @knedlsepp

Comment: @TroyHaskin Please see the answer bellow and answer his comment

Comment: @Jamaisavenir: Well, on itself this question is a duplicate of any 'anonymous function' question here on SO. So instead of asking this, you could either read one of those for clarification, or comment on the answer you were given for clarification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an anonymous function, which is a function that is not stored in a program file, but is associated with a variable whose data type is function_handle. Anonymous functions can accept inputs and return outputs, just as standard functions do. However, they can contain only a single executable statement.
For example, create a handle to an anonymous function that finds the square of a number:

```
    function out=powerplus1(x,dat)
    out=x^2+dat;
     end
```

In another file you write

```
dat=1;
sqr = @(x) powerplus1(x,dat);
a = sqrplusone(5)
```

Then `a` will be 26.

Variable `sqrplusone` is a function handle. The @ operator creates the handle, and the parentheses () immediately after the @ operator include the function input arguments. This anonymous function accepts a single input x, and implicitly returns a single output, an array the same size as x that contains the squared plus one values.
Find the square plus one of a particular value (5) by passing the value to the function handle, just as you would pass an input argument to a standard function.

```
a = sqrplusone(5)
a =
   26
```

Comment: I have tried to give you an example with 2 argument, but I got some errors. If anyone else can , help him. I think he want something like this : `function out=mypower2(x,dat)`
    `out=x^2+dat;`
     `end`
 `sqr = @(x) mypower2(x,dat)`
sqr(5)=?

Comment: Yes, I exactly need to know that @Electricman

Comment: @Electricman When you create an anonymous function with variables not in the `@(...)` list (like `dat` in this case), they need to be defined already because the anonymous function will store their values for later execution.  See [Parameterizing Using Anonymous Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html#bsgprpq-8) for an example.

Comment: I have edited the my answer. @Jamaisavenir

Comment: Thanks @TroyHaskin The answer is edited, Hope its correct.